# Accesing Web form page textbox control in an MVC solution

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have added a Web form page Sample.aspx into an MVC solution. Now in the Sample.aspx.cs page, I am unable to access web form controls. 
For Eg I have a textbox control with id "txtBox1". In Sample.aspx.cs I have txtBox1.Text = "Hello"; Here I am getting error "The name txtBox1 does not exist in current context". Please help.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? Is your `.designer.cs` file intact? The IDE relies on this file to provide the “glue” between a Web Form Page and its code behind. Without it, the IDE isn’t able to detect the controls on the page.

Comment: Its also worth noting: Web Forms and MVC are two distinct approaches for assembling your web application. They can coexist in the same solution, but any given page will _either_ be served via Web Forms _or_ it will use MVC. You _can_ use an ASPX file as your view in MVC, but it won’t have access to the Web Forms event model.